# How to get the last inserted id, and the name of the column with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a QueryBuilder where you can insert dynamically, after that I would like to return the last row inserted, so far I'm getting the last inserted Id with pdo.

```
$last_id =  $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
```

After that i need to do a query

```
$statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE id = :id");
```

The problem is that my column

> Id

Doesn't call like that all the time, sometimes it name is **id_user** or **id_work**, etc.

What i need is to get the column name of where PDO is getting the last Id.

Answer (score 1):

No direct way to know the field name, and there are two solutions.

1) If less tables, you can build an array to save the "id" field directly. for example :

```
$tables = ["table_1" : "id_user", "table_2" : "id_work"]
```

and you can use the $tables[$table_name] instead of the id in your SQL.

2) If you don't know which tables will be used, you can analysis the table directly via PDO before you generate the query sql.

For example

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('DESC tablename');
$stmt->execute();  
$table_fields = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); 
foreach($table_fields as $field){
    if($field["Extra"] == "auto_increment"){
       $field_id_name = $field["Field"];
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the Extra column can have other values in it, so it's possible that a column could be auto_increment and something else at the same time. I can't think of an example (the only other thing I know is Extra is for generated columns, which can't be an auto_increment), but maybe there will be something in the future. So it'd be better to search for "auto_increment" as a substring instead of using `==`.